# How to name a column in a data.frame as the name of the data frame, within a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes; each dataframe has the same column names and the same number of columns (2):

```
> str(read_counts_list)
List of 12
 $ AM1:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ read_count: num [1:1978] 1383 0 396731 40 5889 ...
 $ AM2:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ read_count: num [1:1978] 930 0 293379 24 3051 ...
 $ AM3:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ read_count: num [1:1978] 1321 0 408655 23 2353 ...
```

and so on up to 12 data frames.

What I want to do now is to change the name of the second column in the data frames ("read_count") to be the name of the data frame.
So something looking like this:

```
List of 12
 $ AM1:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ AM1: num [1:1978] 1383 0 396731 40 5889 ...
 $ AM2:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ AM2: num [1:1978] 930 0 293379 24 3051 ...
 $ AM3:'data.frame':    1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA     : chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ AM3: num [1:1978] 1321 0 408655 23 2353 ...
```

Of course the idea is not to do it manually with sth like <-c("name1","name2"); I have several dataframes and I will add more later.

What I have tried so far:

```
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- names(read_counts_list["x"]))
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- names(read_counts_list)["x"])
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- names(read_counts_list[x])) #invalid subscript type
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- names(read_counts_list)[x])
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- names(read_counts_list[[x]])) #invalid subscript type
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- deparse1(substitute(x)))
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- deparse(quote(x)))
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- deparse(substitute(read_counts_list["x"])))
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(read_counts_list,function(x) colnames(x)[2] <- paste0(names(read_counts_list["x"])))
```

All these options either give a strange list where I lose all my data or give error.

Reading here I found a code that changes the name of the column, but the problem is that it deletes the name of the data frames:

```
read_counts_list_t <- lapply(names(read_counts_list),function(i){
  x <- read_counts_list[[i]]
  #set 2nd column to a new name
  names(x)[2] <- i
  #return
  x})
> str(read_counts_list_t)
List of 12
 $ :'data.frame':   1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA: chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ AM1  : num [1:1978] 1383 0 396731 40 5889 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ miRNA: chr [1:1978] "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7a-2-3p" "let-7a-5p" "let-7b-3p" ...
  ..$ AM2  : num [1:1978] 930 0 293379 24 3051 ...
```

- code by:zx8754 -

Then I found something that worked but I really did not understand the code, I would not be able to reproduce it e.g. with a different column, or a sligthly different scenario:

```
read_counts_list_t <- Map(
      function(x,n) setNames(x,c(names(x)[1],n)),
      read_counts_list,names(read_counts_list)
    )
```

- code by: Axeman -

If someone knows a way of doing this with simple apply, colnames, names functions would be great :D or if you could explain what the last code is doing (yes, I looked ?Map but I was "loster" after that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a loop of this style, using the names of your list to be assigned in a specific name of your dataframes:

```
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(read_counts_list))
{
  names(read_counts_list[[i]])[2] <- names(read_counts_list)[i]
}
```

An example:

```
#Data
LS <- split(iris,iris$Species)
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(LS))
{
  names(LS[[i]])[5] <- names(LS)[i]
}
```

Output (Only first element):

```
LS[[1]]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width setosa
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1 setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1 setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2 setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 setosa
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3 setosa
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2 setosa
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4 setosa
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2 setosa
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5 setosa
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2 setosa
26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2 setosa
27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4 setosa
28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2 setosa
29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2 setosa
30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2 setosa
31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 setosa
32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4 setosa
33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1 setosa
34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2 setosa
35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2 setosa
37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2 setosa
38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1 setosa
39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2 setosa
40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa
41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3 setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa
43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6 setosa
45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4 setosa
46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3 setosa
47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2 setosa
48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2 setosa
49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa
50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2 setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setNames` with a `Map`.

```
LIST <- Map(setNames, LIST, as.data.frame(t(cbind(sapply(LIST, names)[1,], names(LIST)))))
```

#### Result

```
str(LIST)
# List of 3
# $ AM1:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ miRNA: num [1:5] 0.7111 -0.9337 -0.0507 -0.4526 1.4833
# ..$ AM1  : num [1:5] 1.382 -0.5125 -0.0438 -1.091 0.8535
# $ AM2:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ miRNA: num [1:5] 0.563 1.256 -1.104 0.367 -0.516
# ..$ AM2  : num [1:5] 0.914 1.308 -0.839 0.403 -1.091
# $ AM3:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ miRNA: num [1:5] 0.548 -1.377 2.179 2.264 0.892
# ..$ AM3  : num [1:5] -0.0564 0.6623 -0.7863 -1.5744 0.3109
```

---

*Data:*

```
LIST <- list(AM1 = structure(list(miRNA = c(-2.51829139109263, -0.877872477016629, 
-0.25969747064056, 1.22571401548266, 0.938000291163749), read_count = c(0.766054639939597, 
-0.748508051788698, 1.2388957678652, -0.169632288961075, 1.60331976703024
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), AM2 = structure(list(
    miRNA = c(-1.38505365651707, -0.354183187247905, -0.00163202119006995, 
    0.596080469170588, -0.480439453674378), read_count = c(0.46622524539987, 
    -2.06658132516899, -0.448024554783029, -0.371688827763805, 
    0.214663638296237)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), AM3 = structure(list(miRNA = c(-0.64657040576356, -1.17865215943876, 
0.181937607228803, 0.186619326022144, -1.26531611982735), read_count = c(-1.20975273029628, 
-0.256061901740592, -0.036373286788934, 0.988560967485261, 0.422093433323588
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)))
```